# Div Alignment issue in internet explorer 9

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a Div Alignment issue in internet explorer 9(not in ie9.It may be in latest browsers)

I have two divs.First one should be in fixed width and Second one should re-size according to the screen resolution change.

I wrote the below code

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
     <div style = "float:left;width:240px;background-color:blue; height:100px"> 
    </div>

    <div  style = "float:left;width:100%;background-color:red;height:100px">
    </div>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

However the out put came like screen shot 1.

I have to arrange the two dives side by side as like the screen shot 2.

Any help on this issue is Appreciated.

Thanks.

**Screen Shot 1**
[image: Div not aligned]

**Screen Shot 2**
[image: Div aligne]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4c5bc/1/

apply a margin-left to the 2nd div and remove it's float.

Answer (score 0):

you can't specify a width of 100% on the second box. that will stretch it to the full width. try to give either a % width to the first element or assign the correct pixel width to both elements

Answer (score 0):

remove one of the floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/6SwwK/